# Filter unrelated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have 2 tables

```
TABLE 1 (named)  coursescores
studentCode,CourseCode,Garde,MajorCode,Score

TABLE 2 (named) MajorCourses
MajorCode,CourseCode,...
```

I want to fetch CourseCodes that are not related to Majorcode in TABLE 1 based on refrence table that is

MajorCourses

i want to get those coursecodes that are unrelated to majorcode in table 1

can anybody help me write the query
thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `not exists`. That would look like:

```
select cs.*
from coursescores cs
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from majorcourses mc 
    where mc.coursecode = cs.coursecode and mc.majorcode = cs.majorcode
)
```

Comment: thanks GMB it was a great help and save my time